# Two Domains, 1 Shared Server, .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I looked through a lot of the other "two domains, one server" questions and didn't see exactly what I'm looking for...

I have two domains, www.example1.com and www.example2.com.  They are in a shared hosting environment with apache.  I want:

A)  example1.com to just load the normal index.html file (on a wordpress install)
B)  example2.com to go to a subfolder /forums/

So, in other words, I want example1.com to be my main (normal and happy) domain and example2.com to only load up the /forums/ directory.

I'm thinking that I may only need a rewrite rule for example2.com going to /forums/?

I hope that makes sense :). Thanks so much for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root folder of your domain.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

#if on www.example1.com domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com$ [NC]
#and not an existing file of directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#then send all requests to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


#if on www.example2.com domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example2\.com$ [NC]
#if not already in forums directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forums/ [NC]
#rewrite requests to forums directory
RewriteRule (.*) forums/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply!

Using your code, example1.com does indeed load index.php just fine.

However, when example2.com loads, I get a 404 error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ooops, I meant a 500 Internal Server Error (not a 404).

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll give it a test tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful to someone. After scanning and trying various methods following seems to work perfectly. I am using Apache server. In my htaccess file, after IfModule I added `<If>` condition and it works fine.

```
<IfModule>
.
.
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.xyzs.co.uk'">

    Redirect    permanent   /xyz1   /yyy1
    Redirect    permanent   /xyz2   /yyy2
    Redirect    permanent   /xyz3   /yyy3
    Redirect    permanent   /xyz4   /yyy4
<If>
```

More reading: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html